# "lein ring uberwar" just hanging there

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, clojure, ring

I'm trying to figure out how to create uberwar from Clojure Ring and Compojure application in Eclipse Mars with Counterclockwise on Windows.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://flowa.fi/blog/2014/04/25/clojure-gae-howto.html), and I'm basically doing this:

1. in package explorer, I right click and create new Clojure project
2. right click newly created project, Leiningen, Generic Leiningen Command Line, enter `lein new compojure-app gae-app-demo` as per tutorial
3. this creates the Hello World app which I can run locally without any problems
4. then I go on and in the same way as in step 2 run `lein ring uberwar`
5. This starts new Console window which doesn't output anything and basically hangs until I manually stop it. It doesn't output anything, it doesn't report any errors, and it doesn't create war in target folder.

I've checked several other tutorials and I didn't find anybody having problems with creating uberwar. Where can I start debugging this, am I doing something wrong? This is one of the basic things one needs to do with every Ring/Compjure application, so it should be something simple I'm missing I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do step 1, you create a generic project, with CCW using leiningen in the background. With step 2, you create another project inside, using the `lein new` command. I don't think this is what you want.

Since you want it all from Eclipse/CCW, the first thing is to get the latest version (0.34.0 as I write) and install it (instructions: http://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#install-as-standalone-product).

Use the wizard to create your project, but change the text `default` in the `Leiningen template` field with `compojure-app`. Wait a few secs after hitting enter, as leiningen will download your deps.

Open `project.clj`. Right-click for the menu and select `Leiningen | Generic Leiningen Command Line` (or Alt+L then L), to open the lein prompt.

Type `uberjar` (this replaces `<task>` at the prompt) then hit enter. Wait a few secs and watch the status of the jar being built in the console tab.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use terminal and type `lein ring uberwar` in the same directory in which is your project?

Comment: Yes! Yes it does, it creates a war through command line. Any idea why not through Eclipse? I'd like to not have to drop into command line for this.